# JHipster-Registry Swagger UI for microservice says invalid_token

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I setup the following components using Jhipster (version of generator-jhipster: @ 5.0.1)

- Gateway
- Microservice1
- Jhipster Registry
- Keycloak as auth server

Everything works fine so far.

In Jhipster Registry, when I go to **Administration** >> **API**
It opens up Swagger UI. Swagger UI lists the apis for Jhipster-Registry and gateway. But it gives error when the microservice is selected in the drop down. Swagger UI From Gateway (Administration >> API) works fine. Only from registry it does not work.

Please let me know if I am missing some configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the JHipster Registry to manage an OAuth2 microservice architecture, you need to enable the `oauth2` profile when running the JHipster Registry.  You will then use Keycloak to log in to the registry and manage the services.

Comment: In the docker-compose configuration, I see it is enabled as follows:

- SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,native,swagger,oauth2

Is this not the right one?

Comment: It worked. I enabled the oauth2 profile in the microservice. Thanks a ton @Jon Ruddell

Comment: @iwekesi How did you fix that? I have the same issue but I couldn't find a solution.